# post request by javascript from other domains

Tags: javascript, http, post, request

As I know, when a POST request has been submitted, it sends Header and Parameters to the web server and it gets the response.

I saw a Javascript Post request in a website that it returns a response, but when I send that Post request from my website, it returns error :

500 Internal Server Error

**HEADERS**

Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 30 Nov 2015 15:03:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=47C9E12F87FC7345358782F6DA7C00E0; Path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

**BODY**

Internal Server Error!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Look at the *request* that is causing the server to error. 2. Look at the *server side* logs to see what the error is. It doesn't do much good to tell us that the server just told the browser that *something* went wrong.

Comment: Are you posting to another domain? Maybe they are restricting the post to their own domain and they are firing the wrong http status code.

Comment: @epascarello 
yes, I post to another domain. but how it can find out that where the JS is running?

Comment: Where what JavaScript is running?